# LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work without LD_PRELOAD

Tags: sh, ld, ld-preload

I'm setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to make newer Qt Mobility be used instead of the older one, so that the non-native apps can use it.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/qtm12/lib
```

One of the libraries is libQtSensors.so.1

but still,

```
/usr/lib/libQtSensors.so.1
```

is used instead of

```
/opt/qtm12/lib/libQtSensors.so.1
```

If I LD_PRELOAD the second library, everything is working, but I can't just preload all the qt mobility libraries, as it's not a library that is used always.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your OS/distribution?

Comment: I'm using this on Maemo.
LD_DEBUG=all tells nothing.
Adding /opt/qtm12/lib to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/somefile.conf fixes nothing
it seems that /usr/lib etc. stuff is taken if lib from other location is not preloaded

Answer (score 0):

```
$echo "/opt/qtm12/lib/" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/qtm12.txt

$ldconfig -v
```

Comment: Still the /usr/lib/ versions of libraries are used

Comment: Then i would say put /opt/qtm12/lib/  in /etc/ld.so.conf in first line. http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/ldconfig/